# Firebase returning unexpected values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the following, I will try to explain my problem which I have while retrieving data from the Firebase database using AS.

**Application's structure:** Currently including two activities, *main-menu* and *chat*. Activity chat is displaying messages, usernames and icons (user type i.e admin & online-status)

In order to get the online-status in a chat-room, for each message the username is stored in an ArrayList and passed to a second Database Reference (first Reference is for messages) which iterates through all names and retrieves the timestamp accordingly.

**The issue:** While this is working as expected I have noticed something not functioning, especially upon the application's *first launch*, when online-status is displayed completely *random*. In order to fix this, it is required to leave the chat activity, return to the main-menu and reenter the chat-room. Afterwards everything is displayed correctly.

I have noticed that messages and usernames are returned exactly as expected, timestamps although are randomized, leading to the online status being displayed either as online for all messages or the first half offline, second half online.

Below, I'm including code snippets as well as screenshots. If you have suggestions on how to improve my code or any useful links let me please know, I'm still a beginner :)

```
public void chatLinstenerFirebase() {
    chatMessageCap();
    playerNames.clear();
    playerOnlineResult.clear();
    // Path holding the current administration information in the Database
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/chat/messages");

    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            execChat.loadUrl("https://*****/exec32014472?uid=" + UUID);

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            // Example for keyParts[] = 1519214361812@user@player
            String keyParts[] = key.split("@");
            ArrayList<String> nameParts = new ArrayList<>();
            // Storing username
            nameParts.add(keyParts[2]);
            for(String res : nameParts) {
                res = keyParts[2];
                // Storing username for second database Reference
                playerNames.add(res);
            }
            // Storing player type i.e user/mod/admin
            String playerType = keyParts[1];

            if(playerType.equals("dev")) {
                playerTypeIcon.add(R.drawable.devicon);
            }
            if(playerType.equals("user")) {
                playerTypeIcon.add(0);
            }
            if(playerType.equals("mod")) {
                playerTypeIcon.add(R.drawable.modicon);
            }
            if(playerType.equals("admin")) {
                playerTypeIcon.add(R.drawable.adminicon);
            }

            // Displaying time when message was sent
            long timestamp = Long.parseLong(keyParts[0]);

            Date localTime = new Date(timestamp);
            String format = "HH:mm";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            String formattedDate = sdf.format(localTime);

            timestampResult.add(formattedDate);
            messageResult.add(value);

            // Getting player timestamps to append online/offline icon
            if (playerNames.size() >= message_count) {
                // Iterate through all players in the chat-room
                for (String n : playerNames) {
                    bDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/lastonline/" + n);

                    bDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            timestampOfPlayer = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            long currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            if (timestampOfPlayer + 300000 >= currentTimeStamp) {
                                playerOnlineResult.add(R.drawable.playeronline);
                            }
                            if (timestampOfPlayer + 300000 < currentTimeStamp) {
                                playerOnlineResult.add(R.drawable.playeroffline);
                            }

                            if (playerOnlineResult.size() >= message_count) {
                                result();
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        ...
        ...

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            playerNames.remove(0);
            messageResult.remove(0);
            timestampResult.remove(0);
            playerTypeIcon.remove(0);
            playerOnlineResult.remove(0);
        }
        ...
        ...
    });

}
public void result(){
        adapter = new ChatAdapter(this, playerNames, messageResult, timestampResult, playerTypeIcon, playerOnlineResult);
        messagecontainer.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

[Screenshot: left side shows wrong online status on first launch, right side works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA352.png)

Answer (score 0):

> The issue: While this is working as expected I have noticed something not functioning, especially upon the application's first launch, when online-status is displayed completely random. In order to fix this, it is required to leave the chat activity, return to the main-menu and reenter the chat-room. Afterwards everything is displayed correctly

I think in your `main-menu have code update status online or in chat-room , so you need update again status when resume application

Comment: This might work, although it is still interesting to me why my approach is not working as expected. I've been thinking about calling the method twice on application first-time chat activity start. That way I don't have to call additional data each time in the main-menu.